# Rotate Object Slowly in React Three Fiber App with Use Cannon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

im making a simple tetris like in a react app using react-three-fiber and use-cannon. i want to rotate objects/meshes when i click them and i want to make this rotation smoothly. how i can do that?

object's code:

```
export function HomeLink() {

const [ref, api] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: [0, 0, 0], args: [6, 2, 2] }))

return(
    <mesh ref={ref} scale={[6, 2, 2]} onClick={() => api.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2)}>
        <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry"/>
        <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="red"/>
    </mesh>
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the angularVelocity property from the api :

```
api.angularVelocity.set(0, 0, -2)
```

which would in term for your issue give :

```
export function HomeLink() {

const [ref, api] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: [0, 0, 0], args: [6, 2, 2] }))

return(
    <mesh ref={ref} scale={[6, 2, 2]} onClick={() => api.angularVelocity.set(0, 0, -2)}>
        <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry"/>
        <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="red"/>
    </mesh>
)};
```